# Creating a GUI with multiple panels and one frame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I am trying to create a simple GUI.  I have a menu bar that is filled with various JMenuItems.  Each menu item should link to a different "window".  Currently, I am thinking the best way to do this is to create a single frame, and create various JPanels.  My ActionListeners will toggle visibility of the different panels, and only one panel should be visible at a time.  Is this the best way to go about the task? Or is there a better workaround.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the best way is to use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) of which there's a great tutorial (please see the link), and many examples online including in this very forum, several of which I've written, including:

- [Java CardLayout Main Menu Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893078/java-cardlayout-main-menu-problem/6893133#6893133)
- [Change size of JPanel using CardLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414177/change-size-of-jpanel-using-cardlayout/5414770#5414770)
- [Java CardLayout JPanel moves up, when second JPanel added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695387/java-cardlayout-jpanel-moves-up-when-second-jpanel-added/5695659#5695659)
- [Java swing; How to toggle panel's visibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600051/java-swing-how-to-toggle-panels-visibility/5600247#5600247)
- [Clear components of JFrame and add new componets on the same JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027849/clear-components-of-jframe-and-add-new-componets-on-the-same-jframe/8027858#8027858)
- [gui multiple frames switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668132/gui-multiple-frames-switch/5670370#5670370)
- [JLabel displaying countdown, java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811064/jlabel-displaying-countdown-java/6811186#6811186)

Comment: See also [Working with 2 or more frames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889922/working-with-2-or-more-frames/7890456#7890456).

Comment: For an example specific to `CardLayout`, see also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665156/calling-awt-frame-methods-from-subclass/5786005#5786005).

Answer (score 4):

[JTabbedPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html) is already implemented for you!
JTabbedPane's [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html).

Comment: See also [Working with 2 or more frames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889922/working-with-2-or-more-frames/7890456#7890456).